# Google Analytics not sending data from mobile

Tags: mobile, google-analytics, real-time, universal-analytics

I have a website with a few webpages that have GA universal tracking code. When I visit the site from a desktop, I am getting the real time data absolutely fine as expected. However, when I visit the site from a mobile (Android on Samsung S6 Edge plus), I don't see any real time data or any other data. Why is it happening?

Comment: No idea, but you can use Chrome to debug your mobile requests: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging. Might give you a clue what's happening.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is about Google Analytics tracking and is not programing related might have better luck on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/